# Boolean expression, doPost servlet returning too many games

Tags: java, html, json, servlets, boolean

The `doPost` is returning games that are over 5 minutes long in playtime even tho when i have entered 5 min max as a parameter in the HTML Form. Why? I have no clue. I have printed out all the parameters that is used in the `Boolean` expression to see if they contain the correct values and they seem to do so. here is examples of that print:

> Info:   owned: false minPlayers :3 chosenPlayers :1 maxPlayers :6
>   chosenPlaytime :5 gameTime :90 Info:   owned: true minPlayers :2
>   chosenPlayers :1 maxPlayers :-1 chosenPlaytime :5 gameTime :-1 Info:
>   owned: false minPlayers :2 chosenPlayers :1 maxPlayers :6
>   chosenPlaytime :5 gameTime :90 Info:   owned: false minPlayers :1
>   chosenPlayers :1 maxPlayers :1 chosenPlaytime :5 gameTime :50 Info:
>   owned: false minPlayers :-1 chosenPlayers :1 maxPlayers :-1
>   chosenPlaytime :5 gameTime :-1 Info:   owned: true minPlayers :2
>   chosenPlayers :1 maxPlayers :7 chosenPlaytime :5 gameTime :30

This is my code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    //processRequest(request, response);

    String players = request.getParameter("players");
    String playtime = request.getParameter("playtime");

    int chosenPlayers = Integer.parseInt(players);
    int chosenPlaytime = Integer.parseInt(playtime);



    URL url = new URL("http://bgg-json.azurewebsites.net/collection/Dan%20Xxxxxxx"); //hidden by me now
    URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()))) {
        String inputLine = null;
        String result = "{\"boardgames\":";
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            result = result + inputLine;
        }
        result = result + ", \"responseStatus\": 200}";

        JSONTokener tokener = new JSONTokener(result);

        JSONObject joRoot = (JSONObject) tokener.nextValue();

        JSONArray jarr = joRoot.getJSONArray("boardgames");

        int numberOfBoardgames = jarr.length();

        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");

        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet BGGCollectionServlet</title>");
            out.println("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"BGGCollection.css\" />");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            for (int i = 0; i < numberOfBoardgames; i++) {
                JSONObject jObject = jarr.getJSONObject(i);

                Boolean owned = jObject.getBoolean("owned");
                int minPlayers = jObject.getInt("minPlayers");
                int maxPlayers = jObject.getInt("maxPlayers");
                int gameTime = jObject.getInt("playingTime");
                int rating = jObject.getInt("rating");

                System.out.println("owned: " + owned + " minPlayers :" + minPlayers + " chosenPlayers :" + chosenPlayers + " maxPlayers :" + maxPlayers + " chosenPlaytime :" + chosenPlaytime + " gameTime :" + gameTime);

                if (owned && (minPlayers <= chosenPlayers && maxPlayers >= chosenPlayers) && chosenPlaytime <= gameTime) {
                    String thumbNail = jObject.getString("thumbnail");
                    String image = jObject.getString("image");
                    String gameName = jObject.getString("name");

                    if (rating >= 9.0) {                            
                        out.println("<div class=\"boardgame good\">");
                    } 
                    else {                            
                        out.println("<div class=\"boardgame\">");
                    }

                    out.println("<h1 class=\"gameName\">" + gameName + "</h1>");
                    out.println("<p><a href=\" " + image +  "  \"   target=\"_blank\"><img class=thumbnail src=" + thumbNail + "></a></p>");
                    out.println("<p class=\"gameDetails\">Speltid: " + gameTime + "</p>");
                    out.println("<br>");

                    if (minPlayers == maxPlayers) {
                        out.println("<p class=\"gameDetails\">" + minPlayers + " Spelare" + "</p>");
                    } 
                    else {                            
                        out.println("<p class=\"gameDetails\">" + minPlayers + " - " + maxPlayers + " Spelare" + "</p>");
                    }

                    if (gameTime == -1) {
                        out.println("<p class=\"gameDetails\">Speltid: " + "?" + "</p>");
                    }

                    out.println("</div>");
                }
            }


        out.println(" <div class=\"sokruta\"><h1>Sök Spel</h1><br><form method=\"post\">"
                + "<p>Antal spelare: <input type=\"number\" name=\"players\" min=\"1\" max=\"12\" \n"
                + "value=\"" + players + "\"></p>"
                + "<p>Maximal speltid: <input type=\"number\" name=\"playtime\" min=\"5\" \n"
                + "max=\"240\" value=\"" + playtime + "\"></p>"
                + "<p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Sök spel\" name=\"button\"></p>\n"
                + "</form></div>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception");

    }

}
```

Comment: `chosenPlaytime <= gameTime` should be `gameTime <= chosenPlaytime`.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It now works :)